# Django API with different levels

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Currently, the project I'm working on has an API like the following:

```
api/
    visitors/  # Endpoint returning list of visitors
    visitor-rates/  # Endpoint returning visitors per time
    gift-shop-orders/  # Endpoint returning purchases at the gift shop
    order-rates/  # Endpoint returning purchases per time
```

What I'd like to do is group the visitor and gift shop endpoints under their own sub-heading. For example:

```
api/
    visits/
        visitors/
        rates/
    gift-shop/
        orders/
        rates/
```

Note that `visits` and `gift-shop` only have the job of listing out the URLs that are available under the respective subheading. So, a GET request to `/api/visits` should return:

```
{
    "visitors": "/api/visits/visitors",
    "rates": "/api/visits/rates"
}
```

In other words, I'd like `/api/visits/` and `/api/gift-shop/` to have the same behavior as the default router view used by Django for displaying the endpoints available in the root of the API (`/api/`).

---

I've tried simply nesting just the URLs together. So, suppose I've defined routers for the visitor endpoints and shop endpoints. I've tried:

```
api_patterns = [
    url(r'^visits/', include(visitor_router.urls)),
    url(r'^gift-shop/', include(shop_router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_patterns)),
]
```

This makes it so that requests to `/api/visits/` and `/api/gift-shop/` respond correctly. However, if I go to `/api/`, no links to `/api/visits` or `/api/gift-shop` are given.

This leads me to believe that I need to nest the routers themselves, not just the URLs. I haven't seen any documentation on doing this, though, and my attempts at coming up with a custom solution have only led to other issues. Does anyone know if there is a simple, standard way to do this that I am missing?

---

tl;dr: How do I nest Django routers?

Comment: did you forget to append urlpatterns ?   `urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_patterns)),
]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is *you don't*. If you're using ViewSets as a way to simplify your views, you need to stick to the rules of ViewSets, and if you want to have nested routes, you can do it with the `@detail_route` and `@list_route` decorators, but they don't express your resources as the rest of the framework does, and it's a manual labor.

The alternative, is using a third-party package called [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers), which is really well done and can definitely do what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I looked pretty closely at the `drf-nested-routers` package, but it seems like it assumes there's a regex for resolving primary keys between each level in the hierarchy. There are no such regexes in my case, and I haven't found a way to override that requirement yet. If you could expand on how to go about using `drf-nested-routers` in my case, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Or, if you could expand on what "rules of ViewSets" you're referring to and how my use case breaks these rules, that would also be really helpful.